# Python List of Lists traversing and updating

Tags: python, traversal, nested-lists

I am trying to change the element at the last index of list elements of z list but getting an error

```
l=['n1','n2','n3','n4']
path=['x','n1','y','z','n2']
y = ['n']
path+= y
d=0
seen = set()
for i in l:
   if i in path:
     f=0
   else:
      d+=1
      seen.add(i)


n=0
z = [[]]*d
for i in seen:
   z[n] = path
   z[n][-1] = i
   n+=1
print(z)
```

`z` should be

```
[['x', 'n1', 'y', 'z', 'n2', 'n3'], ['x', 'n1', 'y', 'z', 'n2', 'n4']]
```

but its giving last index of list elements as `n3` only i.e.,

```
 [['x', 'n1', 'y', 'z', 'n2', 'n3'], ['x', 'n1', 'y', 'z', 'n2', 'n3']]
```

I am not able to figure out why it is not giving the correct result.

Comment: its giving n3 as last elements of both the list elements of the z list. it should give n3 as last element of first list and n4 as last element of second list of z list

Comment: Put some print statements in your for loops to debug the output.

Comment: Tried printing z inside the loop and it gives this result: [['x', 'n1', 'y', 'z', 'n2', 'n4'], [ ]]
[['x', 'n1', 'y', 'z', 'n2', 'n3'], ['x', 'n1', 'y', 'z', 'n2', 'n3']]   but it changes n4 to n3 later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You assign a reference of `path` to `z[n]` in each of your iteration and make a change to the list's last element, so not only `z[n]` changes but also `path` gets the change. You should assign a copy of `path` to `z[n]` instead.

Change:

```
z[n] = path
```

to:

```
z[n] = path[:]
```

Comment: (which also makes `z = [[]]*d` (and the whole `n` variable, really) kind of silly)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in one line:

```
z = [path +[i] for i in l if i not in path]
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 helping.py 
> [['x', 'n1', 'y', 'z', 'n2', 'n3'], ['x', 'n1', 'y', 'z', 'n2', 'n4']]
> ```

Comment: @jay.rana oneline

Comment: courtesy of @jdehesa